# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying limit a bucket access to be accessible by only one Cognito user.

I tried this policy but it's not working

```
{
  Version: '2012-10-17',
  Statement: [
    {
      Sid: 'AllowCognitoUserAccess',
      Effect: 'Allow',
      Principal: '*',
      Action: ['s3:PutObject', 's3:GetObject'],
      Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::testbucketoz123/*',
      Condition: {
        StringEquals: {
          'aws:PrincipalTag/CognitoIdentityId':
            '099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      Sid: 'AllowCognitoUserAccess',
      Effect: 'Allow',
      Principal: '*',
      Action: ['s3:ListBucket'],
      Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::testbucketoz123',
      Condition: {
        StringEquals: {
          'aws:PrincipalTag/CognitoIdentityId':
            '099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad',
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I think there's an issue in the condition, I am trying to check if the user's Identity ID is equal to `099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad`

If yes then grant this user access.

What I am expecting is to allow the user that has Identity ID equal to `099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad` to access the S3 bucket but it not working.

Is there anything wrong with the condition?

I suspect that this condition could only be applied to IAM users and not Cognito users, anyone can confirm that?

Comment: Do all your Cognito users have access to this bucket and its objects? Your policy isn't limiting anything if all of your Cognito users have IAM permissions for this bucket and its objects independently of the bucket policy. You would have to modify the bucket policy to deny all Cognito identities that are not 099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad. Or simply don't give S3 perrmissions for this bucket through IAM to the other users.

Comment: @jarmod Cognito users have permission to ```s3:CreateBucket``` on ```s3:*``` only, they don't have permission to PUT/GET/LIST on ```testbucketoz123``` bucket, and I would like just one Cognito user(the one that has Cognito Identity ID = ```099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad```) to have access on it, that's what I am trying to do

Comment: OK, so what's not working about the policy you've shown? You said that it's not working, but it's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: @jarmod I have updated the description please check it up

Comment: All you've said is "it's not working". How is it not working? It's allowing the wrong users? It's not allowing the 32ad user? What IAM policy do these Cognito users have?

Comment: @jarmod sorry for the confusion, yes, It's not allowing the 32ad user to have access(not only him but all others as well), IAM policy that's attached to all users allowing them to perform the ```s3:CreateBucket``` action on all s3 buckets ```s3:*```

Comment: Typically you would provide the permissions needed by your Cognito users through an IAM role, not S3 bucket policy (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html)). Is there a reason that you are not doing this through IAM policies on the IAM role for each user? See example policies [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html#access-policies) that use `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}`.

Comment: @jarmod After a further research, I did end up in a conclusion that says that we cannot attach an IAM Role to a specific Cognito User, instead we can add the user to a Cognito User Pool Group and attach the created role to that group, can you by any chance confirm this?

Comment: Yes, you configure IAM roles on user pool groups.

Answer (score 0):

If your `CognitoIdentityId` is the `sub` claim, use the "Access Policies" example from [Understanding Amazon Cognito Authentication Part 3: Roles and Policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/)

```
{
  Sid: 'AllowCognitoUserAccess',
  Effect: 'Allow',
  Principal: '*',
  Action: ['s3:PutObject', 's3:GetObject'],
  Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::testbucketoz123/*',
  Condition: {
    StringEquals: {
      '"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub":
        "us-east-1:099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad"
    },
  },
}
```

Otherwise check that the Identity pool attribute mapping has your "Identity ID" mapped to `CognitoIdentityId` and you [set up a trust policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html#trust-policies) on that authenticated role allows for `"sts:TagSession"` so the `aws:PrincipalTag` is valued.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "{your Identity pool ID}"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```